# FAT32 / NTFS + isofs on USB flash drive

Tags: partition, boot-loader, live-usb, ntfs, fat32

I have a bootable USB stick as shown in the screenshot:

```
# dd if=/path/to/os_image.iso of=/dev/sdb
(...everything OK...)

# sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

GParted doesn't recognize any partitions.

[image: screenshot]

The GUI file manager reports the filesystem as `isofs`. The system boots and everything works fine.

The problem is, I want to use the USB stick for a live OS *and* as a storage with PCs and TVs which only recognize FAT32 and NTFS.

I have tried creating two partitions, doing `dd` on `sdb1` and making `sdb1` the only bootable partition, but the system didn't boot.

How to put both FAT32/NTFS and (any) bootable ISO image on an MBR-partitioned disk without using an external bootable USB creator program? I would like to simply use `dd`, as I do now.

Presumably this could be solved using the right bootloader with the right configuration. I just don't know which bootloader and what configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootable usb thumb drive with 2 partitions.**

Windows and others may only see the first partition on a usb device even when there are multiple partitions. Therefore make your first primary partition the fat32 or NTFS partition so windows can see and use it.

partition 1 - ntfs or vfat

partition 2 - ext4

The second partition is where you will store the bootable iso. 
Use grub to load and select what live OS you want to use.

steps:

**1: zero out partition table**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=4
```

**2: Create partitions (use cli “fdisk” or gui “gparted”)**

create partition table "msdos"

create 2 partitions

p1 = ntfs

p2 = ext4 -- *tag as bootable.*

format partitions.

**3: Install grub bootloader to usb device**

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/usbp2/boot /dev/sdx
```

Verify: If these exist all is well so far...

- /mnt/usbp2/boot/grub/fonts -- minimum unicode.pf2
- /mnt/usbp2/boot/grub/i386-pc -- *.mod modules to load in you grub.cfg
- /mnt/usbp2/boot/grub/local -- languages
- /mnt/usbp2/boot/grub/grubenv -- environment variable storage

**4: Create a grub.cfg file for the OS's on this pc**

```
sudo grub-mkconfig --output=/mnt/usbp2/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Test by booting to usb

**5: Copy support files to the usb**

- iso files
- memdisk binary -- get from syslinux
- grub.cfg -- custom for your usb stick. Overwrite grub.cfg created by grub-mkconfig

**Note:** each live iso may require different grub information.

**Note:** If you only get a grub command line, your grub.cfg probably contains errors. Go minimal to start.

**6: Create your custom usb boot installer.**

Copy the MBR and Partition Table

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/custom_boot/cb_mbr.img bs=512 count=1
```

Copy the bootable partition

```
dd if=/dev/sdx2 of=/custom_boot/cb_ext4.img bs=512
```

**7: Create new bootable usb device**

- Delete all existing partitions and clean MBR

  fdisk or gparted (delete partitions)

  dd if=dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1
- restore MBR and Partition Table

  dd if=/custom_boot/cb_mbr.img of=/dev/sdx bs=512
- Restore bootable partition

  dd if=/custom_boot/cb_ext4.img of=/dev/sdx2 bs=512
- Fix the first partition and reformat (fat32 or ntfs)

  fdisk or gparted

My [grub.cfg](http://pastebin.com/LmGhSY2w)

My [Notes](http://pastebin.com/kTz9HkF3)

Comment: here is my [grub.cfg](http://pastebin.com/LmGhSY2w) I live boot gparted, "Super grub disk", Acronis" and others.

Comment: `grub-install` was giving error "Attempting to install GRUB to a disk with multiple partition labels", probably because I set the label for both partitions when formatting them. Then, in GParted, I created a new table with two partitions and formatted them without setting the labels. Still the same problem. I used `--force`, and now I get grub console instead of a menu. In your grub.cfg I replaced your entries by mine, for which I used your PartedMagic entry and only changed `iso`, first argument to `linux` and argument to `initrd`. No error messages from grub at boot. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: See answer for update. Note steps 4 and 5. If you have a grub command line you are almost there.

Comment: Sorry, problem was between keyboard and chair -- a simple mistake in grub.cfg. Everything works fine now, except for the `grub-install` error (both partitions are always called "CDROM", even after `e2label /dev/sdc2 ''` and `fatlabel /dev/sdc1 ''`), but with `--force`, it installs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make this explicit -

- "I would like to simply use dd, as I do now."
- "Windows and others may only see the first partition on a usb device even when there are multiple partitions."

I don't think these goals are practical to achieve, so you will have to compromise somewhere.