# Make Bootable USB from .elf file

Tags: bootable, unetbootin

I want to make a Bootable USB, in order to run some code for a RTOS. I have created the .elf file and I don't know how to make a bootable USB from it. I have tried UNetBootin, selecting Floppy but it never boots. Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: see this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294023/fat32-ntfs-isofs-on-usb/294247#294247

Comment: I don't think that it is the same!! But thank you!